# Node.Js / Express sending data back to the frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm looking to know about the best practice to do something.

I have a Node.Js / Express app and at some point I send the data to the backend part of the app and it then returns a certain value, which I then need to get back into the front-end part.

Usually I could do that through `$.post` and simply wait for the result (on `.done`) but with that particular problem I cannot do that.

Can I send the data back to the app with something like `res.send` and how would I catch that in the front-end?

Thank you!

Comment: When you get your result on the backend, you'll just do a res.status(statusCode).send(results) or something like that. Not too sure how you're set up on the front end. But I'm assuming you have a promise of some sort and you will catch it with your response parameter. Are you using a library/framework on the front end, javascript, or something else?

Comment: @joshbang on the front-end i use simple .ejs and javascript... What I don't understand is how to set up a promise to catch with the response parameter... Thank you for the response!

Comment: Under what circumstances can you not send a POST request and then receive its return result? Could you elaborate on why, and maybe we could work on making that possible instead?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add AJAX/async requests to your app's views. This way app can make a call to the server and get a response, then you will use javascript to handle that data and display it in the app.

It looks as though `ejs` does not support `async` requests, so you may need to use a different templating library/framework - https://github.com/mde/ejs/issues/179.